# General pip commands with Visual Studio

Tags: python, bash, pip, pyinstaller

I'm currently trying to get my python project into an executable. I installed pyinstaller via the python environments on Visual studio:

[image]

and ran the command via this line:
[image]

Despite having found how to *install* packages using pip in this environment, I have not found how to actually *run* package commands. For example, I am trying to run the following pip command to generate an executable of my file:

> pyinstaller --onefile --windowed database.py

Am I missing something here? Where do I do this?

(*ps, I have git bash. Because I installed Python via Visual Studio, I cannot run pip or packages on my general bash shell*)

Comment: "*I am trying to run the following … command: `pyinstaller…`*" What is the error?

Comment: That there is nowhere to actually run these commands. Can’t use the bash shell, says “not found”. That’s because I installed python through visual studio - everything has to be installed through it